# foreach() adds empty lines on file write

Tags: php

I am trying to read and write from a file !
The file will always start with 6 lines.
The default settings file looks like this:

```
10
50
255 255 255
0 255 0
0 255 0
0 255 0
```

I have a default settings file and a another current settings file in which the reading and writing is done.

### I am using 3 globally declared arrays to read and write values:

```
$arrayInputs = array();
$arrayDefaults = array();
$arrayColorsHEX = array();
```

### I start with the default file:

```
if(filesize($inputsFilePath)<=0) {
    if ($defaultSettingsFile) {
        // echo "<br>Reading from $defaultFilePath<br>";
        // Fill $arrayDefaults
        $arrayDefaults = explode(PHP_EOL, fread($defaultSettingsFile, filesize($defaultFilePath)));
        fclose($defaultSettingsFile);
        // Output $arrayDefaults
        var_dump($arrayDefaults);
        foreach ($arrayDefaults as $keyD => $valueD) {
            $arrayInputs[$keyD] = $arrayDefaults[$keyD];
        }
        var_dump($arrayInputs);
        $Timer = $arrayDefaults[0];
        $Brightness = $arrayDefaults[1];
        $arrayColorsHEX[0] = RGBtoHexadecimal($arrayDefaults[2]);
        $arrayColorsHEX[1] = RGBtoHexadecimal($arrayDefaults[3]);
        $arrayColorsHEX[2] = RGBtoHexadecimal($arrayDefaults[4]);
        $arrayColorsHEX[3] = RGBtoHexadecimal($arrayDefaults[5]);
    }
}
```

I fill `$arrayDefaults` and `$arrayInputs`.
So a var_dump on both arrays will look like this:

```
/var/www/mysite/inputs.php:53:
array (size=7)
  0 => string '10' (length=2)
  1 => string '50' (length=2)
  2 => string '255 255 255' (length=11)
  3 => string '0 255 0' (length=7)
  4 => string '0 255 0' (length=7)
  5 => string '0 255 0' (length=7)
  6 => string '' (length=0)
/var/www/mysite/inputs.php:57:
array (size=7)
  0 => string '10' (length=2)
  1 => string '50' (length=2)
  2 => string '255 255 255' (length=11)
  3 => string '0 255 0' (length=7)
  4 => string '0 255 0' (length=7)
  5 => string '0 255 0' (length=7)
  6 => string '' (length=0)
```

**I dislike the fact that it adds another empty element in the arrays but I couldn't figure out a way of fixing it.**

### I continue with the current settings file:

```
else {
    if($currentSettingsFile) {
        // echo "<br>Reading from $inputsFilePath<br>";
        // Fill $arrayInputs
        $arrayInputs = explode(PHP_EOL, fread($currentSettingsFile, filesize($inputsFilePath)));
        $closeFlag = fclose($currentSettingsFile);
        // Output/echo $arrayInputs
        // var_dump($arrayInputs);
        // $arrayLength = strlen($arrayInputs);
        $Timer = $arrayInputs[0];
        $Brightness = $arrayInputs[1];
        $n_1 = 0;
        foreach ($arrayInputs as $key1 => $value1) {
            $n_1 = $key1;
        }
        echo "<br>key1 = $n_1";
        if($n_1>1) {
            $i = 2;
            while(isset($arrayInputs[$i]) && $i<$n_1-1) {
                // echo "<br>arrayInputs[$i]= ".$arrayInputs[$i];
                $arrayColorsHEX[$i-2] = RGBtoHexadecimal($arrayInputs[$i]);
                // echo "<br>arrayColorsHEX[$i-2]".$arrayColorsHEX[$i-2];
                // echo "<br>i = $i";
                $i++;
                // echo "<br>END OF WHILE<br/>";
            }
        }
    } //if($currentSettingsFile)
}
```

### Then I am getting my values from 6 POSTs:

```
if(isset( $_POST['save_values'])) {

    if(!empty($_POST['getTimer'])) {
        $Timer = $_POST['getTimer'];
        $arrayInputs[0] = $Timer;
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['getBrightness'])) {
        $Brightness = $_POST['getBrightness'];
        $arrayInputs[1] = $Brightness;
    }
}

if(isset( $_POST['save_color1'])) {
    if(!empty($_POST['getColors1'])) {
        $arrayColorsHEX[0] = $_POST['getColors1'];
        // echo "<br>POSTarrayColorsHEX[0]= ".$arrayColorsHEX[0];
        $arrayInputs[2] = HexadecimalToRGB($arrayColorsHEX[0]);
        // echo "<br>arrayInputs[2]= ".$arrayInputs[2];
    }
}

if(isset( $_POST['save_color2'])) {
    if(!empty($_POST['getColors2'])) {
        $arrayColorsHEX[1] = $_POST['getColors2'];
        // echo "<br>arrayColorsHEX[1]= ".$arrayColorsHEX[1];
        $arrayInputs[3] = HexadecimalToRGB($arrayColorsHEX[1]);
        // echo "<br>arrayInputs[3]= ".$arrayInputs[3];
    }
}

if(isset( $_POST['save_color3'])) {
    if(!empty($_POST['getColors3'])) {
        $arrayColorsHEX[2] = $_POST['getColors3'];
        // echo "<br>arrayColorsHEX[2]= ".$arrayColorsHEX[2];
        $arrayInputs[4] = HexadecimalToRGB($arrayColorsHEX[2]);
        // echo "<br>arrayInputs[4]= ".$arrayInputs[4];
    }
}

if(isset( $_POST['save_color4'])) {
    if(!empty($_POST['getColors4'])) {
        $arrayColorsHEX[3] = $_POST['getColors4'];
        // echo "<br>arrayColorsHEX[3]= ".$arrayColorsHEX[3];
        $arrayInputs[5] = HexadecimalToRGB($arrayColorsHEX[3]);
        // echo "<br>arrayInputs[5]= ".$arrayInputs[5];
    }
}
```

### And finally I am writing in file:

```
if(!$closeFlag) fclose($currentSettingsFile);

$currentSettingsFile = fopen($inputsFilePath, "w");
if($currentSettingsFile) {
    // echo "<br>Writing in $inputsFilePath<br>";
    // var_dump($arrayInputs);
    foreach ($arrayInputs as $key2 => $value2) {
        fwrite($currentSettingsFile,$value2.PHP_EOL);
    }

    // for($k = 0; $k < $n_2; $k++) {
    //     fwrite($currentSettingsFile,$arrayInputs[$k].PHP_EOL);
    //     // echo "<br>arrayInputs[$k]= $arrayInputs[$k]";
    // }
        
    fclose($currentSettingsFile);
}
```

Please note that I've tried 2 methods of writing to file.

Now, the problem is that for each page-refresh, the code will add an empty line to the file and an empty element to the `$arrayInputs`.
A page-refresh is also done for each `POST`.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: `if ($valueD != '')` ?

Comment: I could've fixed it with `$i <6` inside the `while`. But that isn't the point. What if I didn't know the number of elements of the array ? I would like to understand why it adds empty elements and how to prevent it from doing that, not a work-around.

Comment: array_diff ($arrayDefaults, array ('')) will remove any empty entries in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding an EOL after the last line. That's why `explode` returns 6 records.

After you close the file, the content looks something like this (notice the EOL at the end)

```
line1 EOL line2 EOL line3 EOL line4 EOL line5 EOL line 6 EOL
```

You want your file to look like this (without any EOL at the end):

```
line1 EOL line2 EOL line3 EOL line4 EOL line5 EOL line 6
```

To solve that, you can try one of the following:

**Suggestion 1:** Trim the file content before exploding:

Change the line

```
explode(PHP_EOL, fread($currentSettingsFile, filesize($inputsFilePath)));
```

to

```
explode(PHP_EOL, trim(fread($currentSettingsFile), filesize($inputsFilePath)));
```

**Suggestion 2:** Modify the writing for, as it follows

```
foreach ($arrayInputs as $key2 => $value2) {
  if ($key2 != 0) {
    fwrite($currentSettingsFile,PHP_EOL);
  }
  fwrite($currentSettingsFile,$value2);
}
```

**Suggeston 3:** Use implode for writing to the file, without any `for`

```
fwrite($currentSettingsFile, implode(PHP_EOL, $arrayInputs));
```

Personally, I will opt for the third suggestion.

Comment: Will method 2 and 3 write line by line ? Because I have a C++ code that reads line by line `while(i<6 && getline(settingsFile,string[i++]));`

Comment: Method 2 writes line by line (that is why it is in a for). Method 3 writes all file in one shot, but uses EOL as a separator. Both methods will output exactly the same content, a file that has the PHP_EOL after each line, except for the last one.